# Vertical list instead of horizontal list for drop down

Tags: html, css

Hello I'm trying to create a dropdown menu
But the problem is the dropdown is in a horizontal list instead of vertical,
(Under the 'Health' menu )it also show some indent and idk why.
Tbh, I just followed instructions from a tutorial and I just changed some
of it to look how I want to be. If you could please also correct some of the problems you see that'd be great, thank u very much.

```css
.nav {  /*http://www.mattboldt.com/building-great-navbars-toolbars-display-table/ */
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%; 
  margin: 50px 0px 0px 0px;
 }
 
 .nav li {
  display: table-cell; /* makes it horizontal list*/
  font-family: "Calibri", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px 50px 20px 10px;
  /*border-left:#e0e0e0 1px solid;
        border-right:#e0e0e0 1px solid; */
    }
 
 .nav ul {
 background: #557AB2;  /* background color*/
 text-align: center;
 border-radius: 10px; /* makes the box circular edge*/
 list-style: none;
 position: relative; /* allows to see the box*/
  /* removes excess space in the box (only shows the length from 1st item to last item, not the whole nav bar*/
 }
 
 
  .nav ul ul { /* dropdown menu for 'Health'. 'Nutrition' and 'Mental Health' nested under it.*/
    /* hides nutrition and Mental Health    FOR LIST UNDER HEALTH*/
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      
  }
  
   

  .nav ul li:hover > ul { /*allows drop down for 'Health' */
      display: block;
  }

 
    .nav ul li a {
      display: block; 
      text-decoration: none;/* removes any text decoration (underline) */
    }
```

```html
<nav class="nav">
   <ul> 
    <li><a title="Home">Home</a></li> 
    <li><a href="writing.html" title="Writing tips">Writing</a></li>
    <li><a href="referencing.html" title="APA referencing help">APA   Referencing</a></li> 
    <li><a href="health.html" title="Health tips">Health</a>
     <ul>
       <li><a href="nutrition.html" title="Nutrition   posts">Nutrition</a></li>
       <li><a href="mentalHealth.html" title="All about mental health">Mental Health</a></li> 
     </ul>
    </li>
    
    <li><a href="takeABreak.html" title="Take a break">Take a break</a></li>
 
   </ul>
  </nav>
 </header>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is correct what you need to do is add a css.

```
.nav ul li ul li{display: block;padding: 14px;}
```

Then everything will be displayed in the vertical way

And if you don't want the padding just use

```
.nav ul li ul{padding-left: 0px;}
```

Comment: Thank you! This was much easier to understand as a beginner

Comment: Also, if you dont mind could u please help me center align the menu text in the navigation bar pls

Answer (score 0):

It is because you given it as a `display:table-cell` so. Use `display:block` will solved your issue. Check following.

```css
.nav {  /*http://www.mattboldt.com/building-great-navbars-toolbars-display-table/ */
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%; 
  margin: 50px 0px 0px 0px;
 }
 
 .nav li {
  display: table-cell; /* makes it horizontal list*/
  font-family: "Calibri", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px 50px 20px 10px;
  /*border-left:#e0e0e0 1px solid;
        border-right:#e0e0e0 1px solid; */
    }
 
 .nav ul {
 background: #557AB2;  /* background color*/
 text-align: center;
 border-radius: 10px; /* makes the box circular edge*/
 list-style: none;
 position: relative; /* allows to see the box*/
  /* removes excess space in the box (only shows the length from 1st item to last item, not the whole nav bar*/
 }
 
 
  .nav ul ul { /* dropdown menu for 'Health'. 'Nutrition' and 'Mental Health' nested under it.*/
    /* hides nutrition and Mental Health    FOR LIST UNDER HEALTH*/
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50px;
                        padding: 0;
  }
  
.submenu {
    display: block !important;
  padding: 10px 20px !important;
}
   

  .nav ul li:hover > ul { /*allows drop down for 'Health' */
      display: block;
  }

 
    .nav ul li a {
      display: block; 
      text-decoration: none;/* removes any text decoration (underline) */
    }
```

```html
<nav class="nav">
   <ul> 
    <li><a title="Home">Home</a></li> 
    <li><a href="writing.html" title="Writing tips">Writing</a></li>
    <li><a href="referencing.html" title="APA referencing help">APA   Referencing</a></li> 
    <li><a href="health.html" title="Health tips">Health</a>
     <ul>
       <li class="submenu"><a href="nutrition.html" title="Nutrition   posts">Nutrition</a></li>
       <li class="submenu"><a href="mentalHealth.html" title="All about mental health">Mental Health</a></li> 
     </ul>
    </li>
    
    <li><a href="takeABreak.html" title="Take a break">Take a break</a></li>
 
   </ul>
  </nav>
 </header>
```